# How to teleport after you've killed a villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to teleport after you kill a villager?

I am now making a map called 'The Lost Friends', and there is a challenge called 'Kill the Cute Villager to Win' but I want to teleport the player after he kills him.

Comment: What you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You could probably do something with the UUID of the villager. Or maybe if you place it on a pressure plate when it died it would activate a command block. With mode detail about the situation of the villager it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can track when a player kills a villager using the `stat.killEntity.Villager` objective-type:

```
/scoreboard objectives add KilledVillager stat.killEntity.Villager
```

And you'd run the following on a clock in order to teleport the player and then reset their score so that they aren't constantly teleported:

```
/tp @a[score_KilledVillager_min=1] X Y Z
/scoreboard players reset @a[score_KilledVillager_min=1] KilledVillager
```